# Explicit determination of the open book in $S^3$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I'm familiar with the fundamental concepts of algebraic and differential topology.

How can I determine explicitly the topology of a page of the [open book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_book_decomposition) in $S^3$ given by for example $$f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}, \ f(z_1, z_2) = z_1z_2.$$

Any reference request or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The binding of the open book is a link of $z_1z_2 = 0$ near the origin, which is a Hopf link in $S^3$. I think the fibers $f^{-1}(\theta)$ for $\theta \in S^1 \subset \Bbb C$ are Seifert surfaces of this link: when one goes from $z_1 z_2 = 0$ to $z_1 z_2 = \epsilon$, one resolves the singularity at the origin (which entails two transverse disks intersecting at a point) by making it a Seifert surface of the boundary of the two disks, which forms a Hopf link.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can get the description in the paper of John etnyre.